# Ring of integers is not a field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. $K$ is a number field). Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the set of all algebraic integers. Inside $K$, we have the so-called the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_{K}=K\cap\mathbb{B}$.

It can be checked that $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is a ring. I strongly suspect that $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ is not a field. Is there any easy way to see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2 \in \mathcal{O}_K$. $\frac{1}{2}$ is not an algebraic integer, and therefore not in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an integral extension of $\mathbb{Z}$. If $R\subseteq S$ is an integral extension, then $R$ is a field iff $S$ is a field.

Comment: Beautiful :) Thank you. I have done this exercise before, but couldn't make the connection! I believe for the general statement, $R$ and $S$ need to be integral domains here (No?).

Comment: @Prism Sure, you can assume that.